# iPod 2nd Gen Replacement digitizer not working

Tags: ipod-touch, hardware, repair, digitizer

So I just ordered a new digitizer and middle frame for my 2nd Gen iPod Touch, wired everything up, and the digitizer is not recognizing any finger swipes.

I have not snapped the frame into place yet as I want to make sure I don't have to tear this thing apart again.  The video's I've watched show that the digitizer "should" work when not snapped in.

Is there anything I should be looking for before marking this new digitizer as defective?

Comment: thanks for the edit.  I'm not used to not being able to create my own tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up ordering a new digitizer :-(

Comment: Did it work ok?

Comment: yes, the first digitizer had a micro tear in the ribbon cable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that it's cable is in correctly and it doesn't come up after a hard reboot (hold power button, slide to off, turn on again) - chances are it is defective or not the the right type. Not sure about ipods but the digitizers on iphone generations are listed as not compatible on parts websites!